# Getting a "bad binding form" error in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I have to write a simple program in Lisp that multiplies a polynomial by some factor. In this example, I want to multiply *(x + 5) * 5x*. The answer should be *5x^2 + 25x*.

When I put in `((1 1) (5 0)) (5 1))` I should get `(5 2) (25 1)`. However, I'm getting various errors ranging from `undefined operator TERM in (TERM)` and `bad binding form.` I'm a novice at Lisp and trying to return a list as shown above. Below is my short block of code:

```
(defun get-coef (term)
  (car term))

(defun get-power (term)
  (cadr term))

(defun make-term (coef power)
  (cons coef power))

(defun poly-eval (poly factor)
  (if (null poly) 0
    (let ((term (car poly))
          (let (coef ((* (get-coef(term)) (get-coef(factor)))))
               (power ((+ (cadr(term)) (cadr(factor)))))
               (make-term (coef power))
               (poly-eval (cdr poly) factor))))))
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several problems with your code:

1. You are using `(fun (arg1 arg2))` syntax. It should be `(fun arg1 arg2)`. For example, you write `(make-term (coef power))` but it should be `(make-term coef power)`.
2. Your bindings in `let` are all over the place. The correct syntax is

   ```
   (let ((v1 e1)
         (v2 e2)
         (v3 e3))
     e0)
   ```

   i.e. all the bindings are in one list, and each binding is a list of two elements. Note that the expressions that the variables are bound to (`e1` etc.) are not wrapped in any extra layers of parentheses.
3. `make-term` doesn't use the same representation as `get-power`. In `get-power` you use `cadr` so you need to make sure `make-term` puts the `power` in the right position.
4. Your `poly-eval` doesn't actually combine `(make-term coef power)` with the recursive call to `(poly-eval (cdr poly) factor)`, so it gets lost. You should `cons` the "here"-result to the "there"-result.
5. Your `poly-eval` returns `0` instead of the empty list for empty polynomials.

All in all, your code can be fixed as

```
(defun get-coef (term)
  (car term))

(defun get-power (term)
  (cadr term))

(defun make-term (coef power)
  (list coef power))

(defun poly-eval (poly factor)
  (if (null poly) nil
    (let ((term (car poly)))
      (let
          ((coef (* (get-coef term) (get-coef factor)))
           (power (+ (get-power term) (get-power factor))))
        (cons (make-term coef power)
              (poly-eval (cdr poly) factor))))))
```

giving e.g.

```
(poly-eval '((1 1) (5 0)) '(5 1))
```

resulting in

```
((5 2) (25 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your make-term uses CONS but your get-power takes the CADR:

> (defun get-power (term)   (cadr term))
>
> (defun make-term (coef power)   (cons coef power))

You prolly wanted (list coef power).

(cons 'c 'p) returns (c . p), not (c p).

Now your get-power goes for CADR, the CAR of the CDR, but the CDR is 'p.

Your inputs are *lists* of coeff and power eg (5 1), so it seems the only problem is in your make-term.

Or you can turn around and be consistent with (( 5 . 1)(5 . 0) and then change get power to be (cdr term).

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
(defun mult(term factor)
  (list (* (first term) (first factor))  (+ (second term) (second factor))))

(defun polyeval(poly factor)
  (cond
     ((null poly) nil)   
     (t (cons (mult (first poly) factor) (polyeval (rest poly) factor)))))
```

- Note: first=car, rest=cdr, second=cadr